# Making Docker "undeletable" volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a docker named volume for database data. Now the thing is that when the database container is down and I (or anyone) run `docker system prune` it deletes all the unused containers, images and volumes including the one with database data. Is there a way to make the volume undeletable unless it is explicitly told to?

I suppose I can just mount a host directory to the container without making it a docker volume (and therefore without the risk of deleting it), but using docker volume seems like a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `docker system prune`it is going to wipe out everything. But if you do something like this `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 -v /Users/noname_dev/programming/oracle-database:/u01/app/oracle -e DBCA_TOTAL_MEMORY=1024 oracle-database`

then `/Users/noname_dev/programming/oracle-database` will still be there on your local but the container will naturally be gone till you create it again.